# RibbonApplicationMenu: getting rid of the AuxiliaryPane

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

It so happened that the application I'm working on doesn't operate on documents, so there's no need in displaying the recently opened documents list in the application menu.
But - annoyingly - there are no properties readily available in the `RibbonApplicationMenu` class to hide the unused `AuxiliaryPane` (for which, curiously, the property does exist, but is marked as "internal").
Of course, I can just leave it there - but that's... untidy.

So, here's the solution I came up with.
Hope it will be helpful for anyone else :-)

The general idea is to subclass the `RibbonApplicationMenu`, find the template child corresponding to the menu's Popup, and overrule its `Width` (after a number of frustrating experiments it became evident that doing that neither for `PART_AuxiliaryPaneContentPresenter` nor for `PART_FooterPaneContentPresenter` - nor for the both - could achieve anything).

Well, without further ado, here's the code:

```
public class SlimRibbonApplicationMenu : RibbonApplicationMenu
{
    private const double DefaultPopupWidth = 180;

    public double PopupWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PopupWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PopupWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PopupWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PopupWidth", typeof(double), 
        typeof(SlimRibbonApplicationMenu), new UIPropertyMetadata(DefaultPopupWidth));


    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this.DropDownOpened += 
            new System.EventHandler(SlimRibbonApplicationMenu_DropDownOpened);
    }

    void SlimRibbonApplicationMenu_DropDownOpened(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject popupObj = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup");
        Popup popupPanel = (Popup)popupObj;
        popupPanel.Width = (double)GetValue(PopupWidthProperty);
    }
}
```

As a side note, I tried to find any way to resolve the desired width based on the max width of the ApplicationMenu's Items (rather than setting it explicitly through the DependencyProperty in XAML) - but to no avail.
Given my despise to "magic numbers", any suggestion on *that* will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you set `AuxiliaryPaneContent` to null?

Comment: Or you can perhaps access `PART_AuxiliaryPaneContentPresenter` without subclassing the original menu (`menu.Template.FindName("PART_AuxiliaryPaneContentPresenter", menu);`) and set its visibility to hidden?

Comment: Vlad: I tried the both. Neither worked.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been a while, but I've got another solution to this.  This one does not provide the Popup width property, instead a ShowAuxilaryPanel boolean.  It then goes to Bind the width of the Popup, to the width of the menu item area of the menu.

```
public class SlimRibbonApplicationMenu : RibbonApplicationMenu
{
    public bool ShowAuxilaryPanel
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowAuxilaryPanelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowAuxilaryPanelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowAuxilaryPanelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowAuxilaryPanel", typeof(bool),
        typeof(SlimRibbonApplicationMenu), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this.DropDownOpened += SlimRibbonApplicationMenu_DropDownOpened;
    }

    void SlimRibbonApplicationMenu_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject popupObj = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup");
        Popup panel = (Popup)popupObj;
        var exp = panel.GetBindingExpression(Popup.WidthProperty);

        if (!this.ShowAuxilaryPanel && exp == null)
        {
            DependencyObject panelArea = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_SubMenuScrollViewer");

            var panelBinding = new Binding("ActualWidth")
            {
                Source = panelArea,
                Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
            };
            panel.SetBinding(Popup.WidthProperty, panelBinding);
        }
        else if (this.ShowAuxilaryPanel && exp != null)
        {
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(panel, Popup.WidthProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

worked for me

```
<telerik:ApplicationMenu RightPaneVisibility="Collapsed" >
```