# How to change WPF Ribbon Menu AuxiliaryPaneContent width

Tags: wpf, ribboncontrolslibrary

In WPF Ribbon menu, width of AuxiliaryPaneContent (in RibbonApplicationMenu) is not available. How to change its width based on the items present in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct property to set the Width or Height of AuxiliaryPaneContent. The solution given here may help: [AuxilaryPane Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766168/ribbon-applicationmenu-auxilarypane-size).